# How to fetch data from database comparing some value using PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have some doubt. Actually i need to fetch data as per column value by joining two table using PHP and MySQL .I am explaining my tables below.

> db_specials:

```
id        special                  type

1        Food and Beverage          1

2        Liquor                     2
```

> db_basic:

```
 id      special_id     name

 1         2            aaa

 2         1            Raj

 3         2            Ram

 4         2            Jay

 5         1            Nikesh
```

Here i need to fetch all data from the tables `db_basic` those are associated with Liquor from first table. I am explaining my code below.

```
$res=mysqli_query($connect,"select b.id,b.special_id,b.name,s.type from db_basic as b inner join db_specials as s on b.special_id=s.id where b.special_id=2 order by b.id desc");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
   $data[]=$row;
}
```

I am getting also the proper data. Here problem is `db_specials` also has the delete functionality on front end with insert. Suppose user deleted the row which has `id=2` in `db_specials` table and insert again,in this case the `id` will change 2 to 3. So the query also needs to change accordingly. Here i need to know what should be the best logic so that each time user will not change the query if any specials is deleted and inserted again. Please help me.

Comment: Try to learn Referential Integrity

Comment: If a row from `db_special` table gets deleted and reinserted afterwards will the `special` field contain the same string?

Comment: @VikasUmrao : Can you send any reference link to easily learn.

Comment: @1000111 : The `id` field is auto incremented.

Comment: I asked for whether the new row will contain the same `string` as previous. And also let us know if a particular row from `db_special` table gets deleted what's the effect in `db_basic` table? The corresponding rows in `db_basic` table also get deleted?

Comment: Please check the join query. Here my requirement is i need to get value associated with  `Liquor` from second table.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *id* column, you should rely on the *type* column of *db_specials* table, since it's not going to be auto incremented for each `INSERT` operation. So your query should be like this:

```
select b.id,b.special_id,b.name,s.type 
from db_basic as b 
inner join db_specials as s 
on b.special_id=s.type 
where b.special_id=2 
order by b.id desc
```

---

Also, I recommend that you should change the *special_id* column name of *db_basic* table to *type*, like this:

```
+------+------+------+
|  id  | type | name |
+------+------+------+
|      |      |      |
```

This way, it would be easier for you to construct the query, like this:

```
select b.id,b.type,b.name
from db_basic as b 
inner join db_specials as s 
on b.type=s.type 
where b.type=2 
order by b.id desc
```

Comment: @ Rajdeep : I was also thinking about type. You mean user has to insert type as `2` each time if it need to delete and again insert.

Comment: @subhra Yes, that's correct because *id* column is auto incremented but *type* column is not. While inserting the row again, you can manually insert `2` as a type value. I've further updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

if user deleted  ***2,Liquor,2*** in db_specials and reinsert, you cannot control what the user input in the front end.
*User might be insert **Food,2***

Instead of join the **type** column of **db_specials** with **db_basic**, you should put a checking in the front end, when user click the delete button, prompt a message before delete ***2,Liquor,2*** from the table db_specials,  if there is any special_id=2 in table **db_basic** the corresponding rows will deleted as well.